# How to place feedback icon next to input ALWAYS in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In designing the form When input has a width lower that 100% feedback icon does not place next to it :

```
<div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Input with success</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
         <input class="form-control" id="inputSuccess3" aria-describedby="inputSuccess3Status" style="width: 40%;" type="text">
         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>                    
     </div>
</div>
```

and if I give style to input to has `width:40%` feedback icon place does not changed:

[image]

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/bXN0Y7BTaU)

How I can place feedback icon next to input ALWAYS even when width or display width changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When using the grid cols in the form, make sure it has the `form-horizontal` class. For the `has-feedback` icon, width must be set on the input container. In this case you could use `col-sm-5` since it is ~41% width.

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="inputSuccess3">Input with success</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input class="form-control" id="inputSuccess3" aria-describedby="inputSuccess3Status" type="text">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

[Demo](http://www.codeply.com/go/W9fk62Kz4L)

Comment: Thanks but for some reason consider I can't use `col-sm-5` and I want set width manually

Comment: As you want to set the width manually, the best way is to set the icon as background image of the input, not as separate tag in the html.